# Automatically run chef-client on a data bag update

Tags: chef-infra

I have a data bag with secrets that are getting updated and changed very frequently. Currently, when ever a developer updates the data bag the developer then has to ssh to a server and run chef-client.

While this is not an issue for the odd one or two it is wasting their time. Is there a way where a server automatically converges when it detects that a data bag has been updated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature of Chef. You can set up `chef-client` as a background task either as a daemon or cron job so it will run converges every X minutes. But then you have to wait a bit for the changes to roll out, potentially up to X*2 minutes.